# Should contractions be avoided in formal emails?

Tags: contractions, email, formality

In a formal email of the kind where you begin with "Dear Mr. Surname" and finish with "Best regards", for example, should we use the following contractions? Or are the non contracted forms more appropriate?

- We have -> We've
- We would -> We'd
- There is -> There's
- etc.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603546/2085).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In formal writing, do not use contractions.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up! :)

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted to confirm. Let's wait to see if there are any other opinions here. Thanks

Comment: Why shouldn't one use contractions in formal writing?

Comment: -1 Wildly outdated advice that isn't applicable in any context that hasn't already specified a StyleGuide (in which case your question is answered by that)

Comment: I understand that "we've" isn't really formal, but what about "don't"? Because "I do not like..." doesn't sound really well to me... (But I'm not native EN speaker.)

Answer (score 6):

Giving blanket advice about contractions in "formal" writing is impossible because norms differ by discipline or purpose. When using contractions *doesn't* breach the specific governing norms, you should pursue the greatest clarity and concision, achieved by *avoiding* expanded verbs that are ordinarily contracted. I discuss this in depth in "[The celebration of informality and the unsettled status of contractions.](http://disputedissues.blogspot.com/2011/02/formality-part-4-celebration-of.html)"

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: use contractions where appropriate.

The idea behind banning contractions is to avoid upsetting people who entertain the delusion that there’s something wrong with using them in a formal context. Before you decide that you don’t want to risk offending such people (in case there are any still living), it is important to beware the dangers of avoiding contractions:

You could sound pompous.

You risk trying the patience of those who don’t have a problem with contractions (i.e. anyone who reads your e-mail).

Care must be taken when rewording sentences so that meaning is preserved. For example these two sentences do not mean the same thing:

1. He thought a Christian could not attend church and still be saved.
2. He thought a Christian couldn't attend church and still be saved.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference in meaning in your last example?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev "could (not attend church) and (still be saved)" versus "couldn't (attend church and still be saved)". The different interpretations are: (1) you can be saved without having had attended church and (2) if you attend church, you can't be saved. Although the first phrasing is could be interpreted in either way - "not A and B" is ambiguous.