# "You're" or "you are"?

Tags: writing-style

My colleague and I are working on our style used in communications, and we have a question around whether it's acceptable to use "you're" or if we should always write "you are".

Our style guide says:

> Our tone is conversational, honest, thoughtful, but never familiar or using slang terms

The specific example we're looking at would be in an email from an IT department of a company to employees with instructions on installing a new system. We want a sub-heading at the end to conclude the message.

And so the heading would read either:

- ***You're* ready to use *[product name]*!**
- ***You are* ready to use *[product name]*!**

Which better meets the requirements of our style guide? Is *you're* too familiar? Slangy? Is *you are* too stilted to be conversational? Does it convey thoughtfulness? Could one form be more appropriate than another in different circumstances?

There has been discussion on [using contractions in formal writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4871/should-contractions-be-avoided-in-formal-emails) (of which this question has been tagged as a duplicate), but I feel our style guideline is more nuanced than just "formal".

Comment: You're probably right. The close-vote reason should probably be 'Primarily Opinion Based'. There was a specific instruction to close-vote questions relating solely to specific style guides some time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You're" is definitely more conversational and less formal than "you are", so it's a tough call. "You are" is always correct in written English. I'd definitely use it when you want to emphasize that "you ARE ready to use [product name]!" but if you're addressing the user directly with "you" you're being conversational (and the exclamation point implies that too), so "You're ready to use [product name]!" sounds more natural.

Comment: Contractions can be a real pain for people who do not speak English natively.  In technical writing I have stopped using them even for the marketing type material.

Comment: @Val Good point. In a short story I wrote recently I had a lot of dialog with a non-native speaker who became more fluent over the course of a few years; she deliberately avoided contractions earlier in the story.

Comment: In your examples, both "are" and "'re" sound okay, to me.